# Angular 10 Tabs Component ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material, tabs, angular10

I'm a new learner of Angular. I have a problem with the Angular 10 Material Tabs Component, I'm already tried to follow the angular documentation and other tutorial websites.

The header of tabs is showed up but the content is not. the error shown in the console is like this "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

[screenshot of the error in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD8xB.png)

Here are my codes and I'm imported the MatTabsModule in app.module.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-penilaian',
  templateUrl: './penilaian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./penilaian.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class PenilaianComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" class="tab">
  <mat-tab label="tab A">
    <p>TEST 1</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="tab B">
    <p>TEST 2</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="tab C">
    <p>TEST 3</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. Were you able to solve the issue? If yes then please post the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps. But you are using ViewEncapsulation.None, which means any styling in penilaian.component.css is applied to the children also (remember, using this ViewEncapsulation setting causes no shadow DOM being created here and the styling will be added to the head tag), which means in this case each mat-tab. Furthermore, each tab (child component) will (by default) be initialized (unless lazy loaded) but only gets injected into the DOM when the tab is activated. So in general: It might be, you're trying to target things inside a tab which can not be targeted as the tab is not active. This could maybe explain your errors...?